# Issues binding data finding the ListView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand the Java ListView component and I want to add data on it when I load my fragment, so I was doing it in the `onCreateView` method. Correct me if I am wrong:

```
Public class JobsListFragment  extends Fragment {
ListView listView ;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

@Nullable
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobs_list, container, false);

    // Find the ListView resource.
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobs_list, container, false);

    // Create and populate a List of planet names.
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};

    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.joblayoutrow, planetList);

    listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );
    listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );
    listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );
    listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );
    listAdapter.add( "Eris" );

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
}
```

The problem I am having is with these two lines here:

```
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.joblayoutrow, planetList);
```

So I tried to use inflate and I couldn't find the ListView either. This is my ListView fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".JobsListFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Also, because I am using fragments here, I can't seem to access `setContentView`. Sorry if these are basic questions, I am ditching `Xamarin` after years of frustration.

Comment: May I recommend http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html? There are others but they say the same thing. I'd only repeat it.

Answer (score 2):

First : after return statement, nothing will be executed

Second : use rootVew to initialise which is inside `R.layout.fragment_jobs_list` because whatever is inside `R.layout.fragment_jobs_list` layout, now is inside `rootView`

Third : return `rootVIew`

```
@Nullable
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Find the ListView resource.
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jobs_list, container, false);
     mainListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.mainListView );


    // Create and populate a List of planet names.
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};

    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.joblayoutrow, planetList);

    listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );
    listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );
    listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );
    listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );
    listAdapter.add( "Eris" );

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    return rootView;

}
```